# What is the best way to achieve the behavior of abstract methods from OOP languages in Javascript (es6)?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I am programming in Javascript (es6) while coming in from a Java background. In Java, I commonly write interfaces/abstract classes and this feature is lacking in es6. Commonly, I like writing abstract methods in order to use design patterns, such as the Strategy Pattern. I have seen others try to implement their own version of abstract classes, but I am not particularly fond of it.

Suppose that we have an abstract class called `Animal` and it has an abstract method `cry`. From what I have been seeing, the Javascript code would look like:

```
class Animal {
  constructor() {
   if (new.target === Animal) {
    throw new TypeError("Cannot construct Animal instances directly");
   }
  }

  cry() {
    throw new Error('You have to implement the method cry!');
  }
}
```

And let's say that `Cat` and `Dog` are subclasses of `Animal`. Then, their implementation would look like the following:

```
class Cat extends Animal {
  cry() {
    return 'meow';
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  cry() {
    return 'woof';
  }
}
```

What I don't like about this code is that you have to write exception statements to indicate that a class is an abstract class.

However, I think that there is a better approach using callbacks and factory methods. Instead of having abstract methods for an abstract class, we can pass in a callback function into the abstract class and use that as our supposed abstract method. The `Animal` example can be changed to the following:

```
class Animal {
  constructor(cryCallback) {
    this.cryCallback = cryCallback;
  }

  cry() {
    return this.cryCallback();
  }
}
```

In order to create instances of a `Cat` and a `Dog` object, you can basically create them with a factory method. It would look like the following:

```
function createCat() {
  return new Animal(() => 'meow');
}

function createDog() {
  return new Animal(() => 'woof');
}
```

If you create a `Cat` instance and call `cry`, it would look like the following:

```
console.log(createCat().cry()); //meow
```

The advantages of using this approach are that you are not actually calling an instance of `Animal` because you are forced to implement `cry`. Second, you can hide the implementation of creating a `Cat` or `Dog` object with the factory method.

Please let me know what you think about this approach. Are there better approaches to achieve abstract methods in Javascript?

Comment: Use typeecript, it provides syntactic sugar for the things you are referring to. Typescript also provides optional type checking at compilation time

Answer (score 0):

The first option throwing exceptions is, IMO, much better.

The first reason I think about is:

```
function createCat() {
  return new Animal(() => 'meow');
}

createCat() instanceof Cat // This line is pointless, cat does not even exist.
```

But if you use:

```
class Cat extends Animal {
  cry() {
    return 'meow';
  }
}

new Cat() instanceof Cat // true
new Cat() instanceof Animal // true
```

You have a feature you wouldn't have by using the former.

Edit: you could do a mixture of these two by doing something like this (I didn't check if the code is correct):

```
function factoryAnimal(ctror) {
  const r = () => {
    ctor.prototype = Object.create(Animal);
    const res = new Animal(ctror);
    res.__proto__ = ctror.prototype;
    return res;
  }
  return r;
}

function Cat() {
  return "meow";
}

const createCat = factoryAnimal(Cat);

createCat() instanceof Cat // This should work returning true.
```

Comment: I'm not actually a huge fan of using `instanceof`. Basically it violates Liskov's principle which states: "if a program module is using a Base class, then the reference to the Base class can be replaced with a Derived class without affecting the functionality of the program module". Usually, if you are using `instanceof`, it implies that the two subclasses of the abstract classes could not substitute the abstract class.

Comment: This is true for pure OOP languages. However, `instanceof` is still very useful in JavaScript, which is often used as a functional one.